# Primeness in semi-simple Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals, semisimple-lie-algebras

**Definitions :**

A) An ideal $P$ of $L$ is called *prime* if $[H, K] \subseteq P$ with $H, K$ ideals of $L$ implies $H \subseteq P$ or $K \subseteq P$

B) Let $H$ be an ideal of $L$. The radical of $H$ is $r(H)$=The intersection of all the
prime ideals of $L$ containing $H$.

> **Example :** Let $S_{1}, S_{2}$ and $S_{3}$ be finite-dimensional simple Lie algebras.
>   Let $L=$ $S_{1} \oplus S_{2} \oplus S_{3} .$
>
> Then $S_{1},S_{2}$ and $S_{3}$ are not prime, since
>   $$[S_1 \oplus S_2, S_1 \oplus S_3] \stackrel{\text{bilinearity}}= [S_1, S_1] \oplus \underbrace{[S_1, S_3]}_{0} \oplus \underbrace{[S_2, S_1]}_{0} \oplus \underbrace{[S_2, S_3]}_{0} = S_1 \subseteq S_{1}$$ but neither $(S_1 \oplus S_2) \nsubseteq  S_1$ nor $(S_1 \oplus S_3) \nsubseteq  S_1$.
>   Similarly for $S_{2}$ and $S_{3}$.

**Now**
$$[S_1 \oplus S_2, S_1 \oplus S_3] \stackrel{\text{bilinearity}}= [S_1, S_1] \oplus \underbrace{[S_1, S_3]}_{0} \oplus \underbrace{[S_2, S_1]}_{0} \oplus \underbrace{[S_2, S_3]}_{0} = S_1 \subseteq S_1 \oplus S_2 $$
$$\implies S_1 \oplus S_2 \subseteq S_1 \oplus S_2 $$

$$[S_1 \oplus S_2, S_1 \oplus S_2] \stackrel{\text{bilinearity}}= [S_1, S_1] \oplus \underbrace{[S_1, S_2]}_{0} \oplus \underbrace{[S_2, S_1]}_{0} \oplus [S_2, S_2] = S_1 \oplus S_2 \subseteq S_1 \oplus S_2$$ $$ \implies S_1 \oplus S_2 \subseteq S_1 \oplus S_2$$ 
Therefore $S_1 \oplus S_2$ is prime ideal. Similarly for $ S_{1} \oplus S_{3}$ and $S_{2} \oplus S_{3}$.

**My Questions:-**

> 1.Does $S_{1} \oplus S_{2}, S_{1} \oplus S_{3}$ and $S_{2} \oplus S_{3}$ are the prime ideals in $L$?
>
> 2.What is the radical of $S_1$ for example?

**The source of this question: [On prime ideals in Lie algebra](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206136843)**

I would really appreciate your help .

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: @RicardoBuring ...

Comment: Hint: Remind yourself (or learn) how *any* ideal of a semisimple Lie algebra looks like. Do you see that $S_1 \oplus S_2 \oplus S_3$ contains exactly eight ideals? List them.

Comment: $0$, $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$ , $S_1+S_2$, $S_1+S_3$, $S_2+S_3$ and $S_1+S_2+S_3$

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  Remind yourself (or learn) how any ideal of a semisimple Lie algebra looks like.?
What do you mean ?

Comment: Well good, you got them. In your previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3673945/96384) it was stated, and is still is easy to show, that the full Lie algebra is prime, and that $S_1$ is not (and whatever argument one has for this works for $S_2$ and $S_3$ as well). It should also be easy to see that $0$ is not prime. So there you go for Q1. -- And now after knowing exactly which of the eight ideals are prime, and given it's quite obvious which of them contain $S_1$, what is the problem with Q2?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I cant understand if my ansawer of Q1 is true(That is only the 3 ideals are the only prime)

Comment: For Q2 I cant obtain the radical of $S_1$ for example. 
Is it $0+S_1$ ?

Comment: Q1: For which of the eight ideals are you not sure whether it is prime or not? Q2:Which of the eight ideals are i) prime and ii) containing $S_1$? What is their intersection? Also, $0+S_1=S_1$ so I don't understand why you write it that way.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Q1: I am sure that $S_1+S_2$, $S_1+S_3$, $S_2+S_3$ and $S_1+S_2+S_3$ are all the prime ideals in $L$.
Q2: $S_1+S_2$, $S_1+S_3$ and $S_1+S_2+S_3$ are prime and containing $S_1$. But what is their intersection?!

Comment: Sorry, if you cannot find the intersection of these, I don't know how to help. That's basic.

Comment: $(S_1 \oplus S_2) \cap (S_1 \oplus S_3)  \cap (S_1 \oplus S_2 \oplus S_3)=S_1 $

Is this true ? @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: Yes. Already the intersection of the first two is just $S_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. $S1+S2, S1+S3, S2+S3$ and $S1+S2+S3$ are all the prime ideals in $L$

Q2. $$r(S_1)= (S_1 \oplus S_2) \cap (S_1 \oplus S_3)  \cap (S_1 \oplus S_2 \oplus S_3)=S_1$$